# Find $D \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $D \oplus (A\cap B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, vectors

> If $A \cap B = \{x \in \mathbb{R^3} : 2x_1+2x_2-2x_3=0\}$. Find $D \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $D \oplus (A\cap B)= \{x \in \mathbb{R^3} : x_1+2x_2-x_3=0\}.$

If I have $\oplus$ then I would have to have that $D \oplus(A\cap B) = \{0\}$? Forgetting about this condition for a minute I have that $D + (A\cap B) = \{(v +(x_1,x_2,x_1+x_2), v \in D, (x_1,x_2,x_1+x_2) \in A\cap B \}$. Now from the equality I have $$\{(v +(x_1,x_2,x_1+x_2), v \in D, (x_1,x_2,x_1+x_2) \in A\cap B \}=\{x \in \mathbb{R^3} : x_1+2x_2-x_3=0\} = \{(x_1,x_2,x_1+2x_2)\}$$ so $(v_1,v_2,v_3)+(x_1,x_2,x_1+x_2) = (x_1+v_1, x_2+v_2, x_1+x_2+v_3) = (x_1,x_2,x_1+2x_2)$. I get $$x_1=x_1+v_1 \\ x_2=x_2+v_2 \\x_1+2x_2=x_1+x_2+v_3$$ I'm not sure if I'm getting in the right direction here?

Comment: Your title got cut off before it was completed.

Comment: Also, the meaning of $\oplus$ in your post is not clear. Can you tell us how $\oplus$ is defined?

Comment: It's the direct sum (https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/flynn/genus2/alg0506/LALect02.pdf)

Comment: I also notice that $A$ and $B$ have not been specified, so your question is appears to be just a question about the set $C = \{x \in \mathbb R^3 \mid 2x_1 + 2x_2 - 2x_2 = 0\}$. Was that your intention?

Comment: Yes $A \cap B$ could be denoted as just $C$.

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up, although it would improve your post if you edited these corrections into your post itself.

Answer (score 1):

As this problem is stated, there is no solution, i.e. there does not exist any $D$ as asked for.

The reason is that for any subspaces $D$ and $C$, if the direct sum $D \oplus C$ exists then $C \subset D \oplus C$, because $D \oplus C = D + C$ and for each $x \in C$ we have $x = 0 + c \in D + C$.

However, the set $C = \{x \in \mathbb R^3 \mid 2x_1 + 2x_2 - 2x_3 = 0\}$ is not a subset of the set $\{x \in \mathbb R^3 \mid x_1 + 2 x_2 - x_3 = 0\}$: take $x = (1,1,2)$ as a counterexample.